# App/service that suggests which payment card is most convenient?

Tags: payment-cards, exchange, mobile-apps

I was a happy user of WhatCard (http://www.whatcardapp.com). It was an app for European people, where the user saved their credit/debit cards data, then typed the amount to pay in a foreign currency and the app suggested the most convenient card to use and its fees.

Unluckily, with the new year, this app has been abandoned and it doesn't work anymore. Does someone know a similar app or online service?

Comment: Have you considered using Revolut instead? :)

Comment: I have a similar Italian card and I know N26, but whatcard was different. It calculates every fees of cards you already have in every country.

Comment: But Revolut doesn't have any fees in the first place (except for a 0.5% conversion fee on weekends). Can't really beat that.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about a 1:1 replacement, but these days this should be easy: There are cards with 0% transaction fee and free cash withdrawals worldwide, and you can't get better than that.

Note that the credit card exchage rates are fixed, so there are no "better" cards in that regard. N26 currently (2018) has some good offerings that are available in most of Europe, but there are others.

You can check the exchange rates here

- [Visa exchange calculator](https://www.visaeurope.com/making-payments/exchange-rates)
- [Mastercard exchange calculator](https://www.mastercard.us/en-us/consumers/get-support/convert-currency.html)

Also, if you really want to chose the "best" card, you'd have to check if the yearly price of the card (if any) is worth any savings you have.

But most important thing in Europe is to **never chose the option to pay in your home currency** (common option e.g. in Poland). If you do that, you'll be using an external conversion service with *really* bad rates.